# Error while trying to convert compose file to kubernetes manifest

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to convert a docker compose file to a kubernetes manifest for deployment and after installing the Kompose on my system, I used the command `kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml` for the conversion process but it is not working. The error response is `←[31mFATA←[0m services.web.stdin_open must be a boolean`.

The docker-compose file is shown thus:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Backend / Database
  database:
    image: database
    build: ../backend/database
    volumes:
      - ../backend/database:/data/db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back

  # Backend / API
  api:
    image: api
    build: ../backend/api
    volumes:
      - ../backend/api/public:/user/src/app/public
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "8084:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - front
      - back

  # Backend / Proxy
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ../backend/proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - database
      - api
    networks:
      - front
      - docker-network

  # Frontend / App / Web
  web:
    image: web
    stdin_open: "true"
    build: ../frontend/app/web
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - front

networks:
  front:
    driver: bridge
  back:
    driver: bridge
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Please I'd like help on how I can avoid this error and build the manifest file. I am running this on a windows machine. Also a screenshot of the error is shown in the image attached.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebAcl.png)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change stdin_open to true instead of ”true”

```
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
```